# Android: How to handle multiple tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to perform multiple tasks in Android. I know I can use AsyncTask for this. But my requirement is I want to execute second task only completion of first task. Then will execute the third task only after completion of second task. How it could be possible.
For this I am thinking to use multiple AsyncTasks i mean inside doInBackground of first AsynTask I want to start second AsyncTask. Similarly inside doInBackground of secondAsynTask I want to start third AsyncTask and so on.... Is it ok if I implement like this with out any performance issue or is there any other way of doing this. Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple AsyncTasks and call them in a chain.

E.g.:

Call the first task:

```
new FirstTask().execute();
```

Then FirstTask class overrides `onPostExecute` where it calls the second class:

```
new SecondTask().execute()
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am also thinking the same way. Is there any other way to achieve this kind of serial execution? I don't know Creating multiple AsyncTasks and implementing all it's methods is a good thing or not!!!

Comment: @user435062 Well if you don't have a 100 tasks, then it's fine and pretty useful IMO. You can always continue from a specific task if it for example returned with an error. It's pretty dynamic. Furthermore with the help of a single flag you could make the tasks independent of each other. E.g. you only want the 3rd class executed.

Comment: I am just wondering if we can use ThreadPoolExecutor for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel you could use concat () operator of rxjava.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#concat